# Removing _home_ from Home Page link

Tags: routes

I have a single page selected as home page by ticking "This is for homepage" but now I find link comes up as

```
 http://example.com/index.php/__home__
```

I want the home link to only be

```
 http://example.com/index.php/
```

What do I need to do to get rid of **__home__**?

Comment: Can you update your question with the template code you're using to generate the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__home__` is the pretend URI that Craft uses to identify an element that should be treated as the homepage. The only way you would be able to output it is if you were doing something like this:

```twig
<a href="{{ siteUrl ~ entry.uri }}">
```

You should be doing this instead, though, which will remove it:

```twig
<a href="{{ entry.url }}">
```

or,

```twig
<a href="{{ entry.getUrl() }}">
```